# How i can delete NULL values in dataset in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I had load a data set in neo4j using cypher query. When I load the data, I found some null in between the words.
How to clean the null values.
My aim is to find word count frequency.

I got results
[results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0db8E.png)
some nulls in between words`enter code here`

```
 LOAD CSV FROM "file:///tmp1.csv" AS line
 FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
 FOREACH (w IN RANGE(0, SIZE(line)-2) |
 MERGE (lx:Kbank{word:coalesce(line[w],'NOT SET')})
 ON CREATE SET lx.count = 1
 ON MATCH SET lx.count = lx.count + 1
 MERGE (mx:Kbank{word:coalesce(line[w+1],'NOT SET')})
 ON CREATE SET mx.count = 1
 ON MATCH SET mx.count = mx.count + (case when w = SIZE(line)-2 then 1 else 0 
 end)
 MERGE (lx)-[r:next]->(mx)
 ON CREATE SET r.count = 1
 ON MATCH SET r.count = r.count +1)
 RETURN line
 LIMIT 100
```

for word count
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyBVH.png)
I want delete NOT SET LIST

Comment: Try check null words in case when, https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function in cypher to remove all the `NULL` values :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///tmp1.csv" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
WITH  filter(x IN line WHERE x IS NOT NULL) AS line
...
```